# Can send strings but nothing else

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the server to return thisdict when it receives GETALL as input however anything outside of directly given strings doesn't work. I suspected the encoding but it doesn't seem to be the one breaking it. Any suggestions?

Originally the encoding was a variation of ASCII and UTF-8 but I changed it all to UTF-8 for the sake of simplicity.

```
import logging
import socket

import constCS
from context import lab_logging

lab_logging.setup(stream_level=logging.INFO)  # init loging channels for the lab


class Server:
    _logger = logging.getLogger("vs2lab.lab1.clientserver.Server")
    _serving = True

    thisdict = {
        "Ivan" : "0123",
        "Kiro" : "4567"
    }

    def GETALL():
        return thisdict

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((constCS.HOST, constCS.PORT))
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  # prevents errors due to "addresses in use"
        self.sock.settimeout(3)  # time out in order not to block forever
        self._logger.info("Server bound to socket " + str(self.sock))

    def serve(self):
        self.sock.listen(1)
        while self._serving:  # as long as _serving (checked after connections or socket timeouts)
            try:
                (connection, address) = self.sock.accept()  # returns new socket and address of client
                while True:  # forever
                    data = connection.recv(1024)  # receive data from client
                    if not data:
                        break  # stop if client stopped
                    if data == "GETALL":
                        connection.send(str(thisdict) + "".encode('utf-8'))  # return sent data plus an ""
                connection.close()  # close the connection
            except socket.timeout:
                pass  # ignore timeouts
        self.sock.close()
        self._logger.info("Server down.")


class Client:
    logger = logging.getLogger("vs2lab.a1_layers.clientserver.Client")

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((constCS.HOST, constCS.PORT))
        self.logger.info("Client connected to socket " + str(self.sock))

    def call(self, msg_in="GETALL"):
        self.sock.send(msg_in.encode('utf-8'))  # send encoded string as data
        data = self.sock.recv(1024)  # receive the response
        msg_out = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(msg_out)  # print the result
        self.sock.close()  # close the connection
        self.logger.info("Client down.")
        return msg_out

    def close(self):
        self.sock.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `outside of directly given strings doesn't work` ?

Comment: Anything outside of:
connection.send("ASTRINGOFCHOICE" + "".encode('utf-8'))  # return sent data plus an ""

Comment: My question was more about: what does it mean that it doesn't work? You don't get an output, you get the wrong one, you get an exception, or something else?

Comment: Oh, and by doesn't work I mean it doesn't print anything afterward.

Comment: What data are you receiving on the server socket?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here (obviously):

`connection.send(str(thisdict) + "".encode('utf-8'))`

which is an exception of type:

`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`

You don't see this exception because you're catching it and doing `pass`.

What you want is to have the `""` concatenated and after that the encoding, something like:

`connection.send((str(thisdict) + "").encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Makes sense, however although connection.send("TEST".encode('ascii')) and connection.send(data + "*".encode('ascii')) work, for some reason string variables give no output. Neither connection.send((str(thisdict) + "").encode('utf-8')), nor myString = "myString", connection.send(myString.encode('ascii'))